# Find and classify all isolated singularities of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{z}}$.

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

> Find and classify all isolated singularities of $\displaystyle f(z)=\frac{1}{1+\sqrt{z}}$.

So if $1+\sqrt{z}=0$ then $\sqrt{z}=-1$. Therefore $z=1$. Hence, $1$ is an isolated singularity and it is a pole. I am not quite sure whether my argument is correct here. Is it correct? If not, how may I do it?

Comment: yes it is correct if you've defined $\sqrt{z}$ such that it is holomorphic in the neighborhood of $z=1$. how would you do that ?

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the branch of $\sqrt z$. Usually, $\sqrt z$ is taken to be the branch defined on $\mathbb C\setminus(-\infty,0]$ and $\sqrt 1=1$. In that case, $f$ does not have isolated singularities.

Comment: So can we say that $1$ is a removable singularity?

Comment: It is not a singularity.